# Titanium iOS App : How to Keep application continuously running in background?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I am working on Titanium iOS native app.i want to implement functionality  when my app close the background function or process remains executing.

Answer (score 0):

iOS limits anything like that to happen. You can have background workers, however when the user quits the app, these also will be stopped.

Another solution is having push notifications wake up the app and perform a small task. This also requires the user to enable push notifications.

Same thing goes for Android. It is up to the user. If this were possible on both platforms imagine the battery drain of all apps doing that.